# Getting error on angular CLI isntallation

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install angular/cli on my windows10 64-bit machine, But I am getting the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/angular/cli.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! undefined
npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-19T08_13_51_165Z-debug.log
```

I am trying to execute the following command:

```
npm install -g angular/cli
```

Following are the specifications:

```
node --version
v10.15.1

npm --version
6.4.1
```

Things tried till now as suggested in different posts and forums:

1. Tried running command prompt as Administrator
2. Setting the network settings(set https-proxy and proxy).
3. npm cache clean --force

I don't have git installed on my machine, but is it necessary and mandatory?
I have installed angular previously also(Angular 4) but at that time everything was fine.

Need help.

Comment: Yes you have to install it because cli will create an angular application as a git repo

Comment: is it some new development in latest versions of angular or it was there in initial versions also?

Comment: Try to install package with *@* sign in title `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Comment: If that is the case, I think Angular should mention git as a prerequisite on their official setup guide but I don't find it anywhere.

Comment: Thanks Ivanes....Silly me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install @angular/cli (note the @)

```
npm i @angular/cli
```

This one does not require git to be installed.
I have to admit that this naming is confusing.